# Uncaught TypeError: cannot use 'in' operator to search for "length" in "The uploaded fil..."

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to upload a video file on my app and every-time i try to upload a file i get this message in console:

> Uncaught TypeError: cannot use 'in' operator to search for "length" in
> "The uploaded fil..."

Here is the js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var $errorSummary = $('.error-summary'),
    $videoUpload = $('#video-upload');

$videoUpload
    .bind('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) {
        if (data.result && data.result.files) {
            var errors = '';
            $.each(data.result.files, function(i, file) {
                errors += errorsToString(file)
            });
            if (errors) {
                $errorSummary.html('<ul>' + errors + '</ul>').show();
            } else {
                $errorSummary.hide();
            }
        }
    });

function errorsToString(file) {
    var output = '';
    if (!file.error) {
        return output;
    }
    $.each(file.errors, function(_i, error) {
        output += '<li>' + error + '</li>';
    });
    return output;
}
});
```

I use exactly the same code for upload image files and work great! What i 'm doing wrong ??

Comment: One of the each loops is trying to iterate over a string instead of an array/object. I'm going to guess it's probably the one trying to iterate over `file.errors`

Comment: @aynber any clue how to fix it ?